# Celery is not able to find my django module

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, django-celery

I’m facing the below error when I try to start the celery using the command celery -A blogger.celery worker. I’m running the command from my package directory where I have my celery.py

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blogger'

```
————————
blogger/celery.py
```

```
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
```

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "blogger.settings")
```

```
app = Celery('blogger')
```

```
app.conf.enable_utc = Falseapp.conf.update(timezone='Asia/kolkata')
```

```
app.config_from_object(settings, namespace='CELERY')

——————
blogger/init.py
```

```
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

```
all = ('celery_app', )
————————
blogger/setting.py
```

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/kolkata'CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'—————————
```

Please help me resolve this issue

Comment: Could you provide a general file structure of your project please

Comment: blogger <directory>
 --blog <app>
  —tasks.py
  —views.py
        --blogger <project_root_directory>
  —settings.py
  —celery.py
  —init.py

Comment: It is possible you are running from the wrong directory, let me know if running the command from the `blogger/` directory solves it

Comment: I'm sure I'm running the celery command from this directory path <home_directory>/blogger/blogger

Comment: It needs to be home/blogger, not from within the project folder

Comment: The command should also be `celery -A blogger worker`

Comment: Thanks you so much @montudor . Running the celery command from the base directory worked out.

Comment: No problem I have added an answer to the question. I would appreciate if you marked this as the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your file structure looks like so:

```
blogger/
├─ blogger/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ settings.py
│  ├─ celery.py
├─ app/
│  ├─ ...
```

You must run the command `celery -A blogger worker` in the root folder (`blogger/` **NOT** `blogger/blogger/`). You will also need beat running which can be achieved with `celery -A blogger beat`.

All this information can be found in the [official celery docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html).